# How do I get PyQt4.phonon?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, phonon

I'm trying to run something that needs phonon from python 2.7, and it asks for

> from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon

When I run, I get an error saying no module named phonon.  I've installed python and pyqt via both brew and port, and neither one of them seem to include the stuff to make phonon work.  I also tried adding things like tkinter and gstream to them, but still nothing.

What's the magic sauce to make phonon available to my python script?

Comment: Have you tried installing phonon for pyqt4 comes in a separate package. So try installing that package. In Debian/Ubuntu its called python-qt4-phonon

Comment: @Marcus This is actually the correct answer!

Comment: What is the solution? What we are going to do if we use MacOs not Debian/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try making phonon lowercase and removing .pronon from PyQt4

```
from PyQt4 import phonon
```